# Securely accessing external rest service from Script Editor web part

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, office365, azure-active-directory, office-addins

In SharePoint online, is it possible to SECURELY access an external rest service from a Script Editor web part? Is there a way to get a access token that can be verified by the external service?

```
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script>
        var token = unknowWayToGetJWT(); 
        fetch('https://myserver.azurewebsites.net/getMyData', {
            method: 'post', mode: 'cors',
            headers: new Headers(
                {'token': token})
        }).then(function(r) {
            return r.json();    
        }).then(function(json) {
            document.getElementById(”div1”).innerHtml = json.result;    
        });
    </script>
```

Normally, you create a SharePoint add-in and run inside a iframe (with a well documented authentication flow). This above code has to run inside a Script Editor web part and then you cannot use the SharePoint proxy service or other add-in functionality.

The external server can be registered as an application in Azure AD and have full access to the graph api.

Comment: Did you want to acquire the token silently? And what's the issue you were handling when you acquire the token?

Comment: Yes, I need to get a token silently without jumping to my provider hosted app and back again. I have found posts on how to get a token via a iframe, but it would be nice to understand what is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/03/20/an-architecture-for-sharepoint-apps-that-call-other-services/

Comment: https://stephaneeyskens.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/consuming-azure-hosted-web-api-from-sharepoint-online-using-javascript-and-office-365-identities/

Comment: Normally, we get the token based on the [OAuth 2.0 flow](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749). And in this scenario, I also think the iframe is a suitable way.